# Find out the optimization level in preprocessor

Tags: c, optimization, c-preprocessor, flags

Is there a way in C language to figure out with what compilation flag the program is being compiled? For example (pseudo code):

```
#ifdef -O0
// some code for no optimization
#elsif -O1
// other code for better optimization, etc.
#endif
```

Comment: Why do you need this? What problem is this supposed to solve?

Comment: I am trying to make the code dependent on the set optimization level. This is the problem I am trying to solve. Doing release/ debug defines wont do for my case. But as mentioned in the linked question, it seems like its not possible

Comment: I'm not trying to be sarcastic or anything, but "trying to make the code dependent on the set optimization level" is pretty obvious. But that's the *solution* you want, and not the actual underlying problem. Please read or refresh about the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) as your question is one (asking about a solution to an (for us) unknown problem).

Comment: A 3rd party software is changing the optimization flags for the project, because its bugged. I need to adjust to that. That is the underlying problem.